# Reading from a file and inserting into a database, a good practice

Tags: database, patterns-and-practices, files

I am making an Android application which reads several JSON files and inserts the read information into tables in my database. 
For instance, there are three files:

1. countries.json

   ```
   {
       "countries": [
           {
               "name": "United States",
               "org_ids": [
                   {
                       "id": 1
                   },
                   {
                       "id": 2
                   },
                   {
                       "id": 3
                   }
               ]
           },
           {
               "name": "China",
               "org_ids": [
                   {
                       "id": 1
                   },
                   {
                       "id": 2
                   }
               ]
           },
           {
               "name": "Hong Kong",
               "org_ids": [
                   {
                       "id": 3
                   },
                   {
                       "id": 4
                   },
                   {
                       "id": 5
                   }
               ]
           }
       ]
   }
   ```
2. orgs.json

   ```
   {
       "orgs": [
           {
               "id": 1,
               "name": "UNO"
           },
           {
               "id": 2,
               "name": "Organization of American States"
           },
           {
               "id": 3,
               "name": "INTERPOL"
           },
           {
               "id": 4,
               "name": "European Union"
           },
           {
               "id": 5,
               "name": "The Commonwealth of Nations"
           }
       ]
   }
   ```
3. continents.json

   ```
   {
       "continents": [
           {
               "id": 1,
               "name": "Africa"
           },
           {
               "id": 2,
               "name": "North America"
           },
           {
               "id": 3,
               "name": "South America"
           },
           {
               "id": 4,
               "name": "Asia"
           },
           {
               "id": 5,
               "name": "Europe"
           },
           {
               "id": 6,
               "name": "Australia"
           }
       ]
   }
   ```

Please don't pay attention to the contents of my JSONs, they don't contain real members of the listed international organizations. It's just an example.

I see two ways.

**THE FORMER WAY.**

Store each country with its data to a class instance and define a `SparseArray` contains a country ID as a key and a `CountryInfo` object as a value.

```
/** Each item contains country's ID (key) and respective data (value) */
    private SparseArray<CountryInfo> mCountriesInfo = new SparseArray<JsonParser.CountryInfo>();
```

After reading everything from the files, the data from the `SparseArray` will be inserted into the database.

```
    private class CountryInfo {

    String mCountryName;
    int continentId;
    String mContinentName;
    /** Contains IDs (keys) and names (values) of organizations */
    SparseArray<String> mOrgNames = new SparseArray<String>();

}
```

**Drawbacks.**

- The more JSONS (or the more complex JSONs) the more complex the class
  for storing.
- Data duplication.

**Benefits**

- Reading and inserting does not depend on each other.

**THE LATTER WAY.**

Read and insert without preliminary saving.

**Drawbacks.**

- Database logic and reading logic are mixed.

**Benefits.**

- No any additional classes.
- No data duplication.

Which way is a better practice?

Comment: Can you elaborate *why* you copy the file contents to a database and *how often* this happens?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau, I copy the file contents to the database because I will use `ListView` to display the data and it's a very bad practice to read from JSON periodically in `getView`. As regards to my question, I chose the latter way because it is simpler.

Comment: If you perform the copy multiple times (e.g. each time the application starts), then it is just as bad a practice (misuse of a database) and you might be better off to let the `ListView` serve the items from memory. OTOH, if it is just a one-time data conversion, the technique as outlined by DocBrown is best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(This is a Java question, I guess?)

I am sure you can write a JSON reader which takes an arbitrary processing function and applies that function to every record.  The "processing function" may be passed in a functional way, or if you have only older Java versions available, in form of an interface. This gives you reading logic without any database logic. Then, you provide a specific processing function / interface implementation containing the "database insert" logic.

As a result, you get separated database and reading logic without the drawbacks from your first approach.

This is also known as [Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Comment: thank you. I'm learning the visitor pattern now. But I've got a question. They use `CarElement car = new Car();` on the [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). Is there any difference between `CarElement car = new Car();` and `Car car = new Car();`?

Comment: @RedPlanet: In the context of the `main` function in that specific example? No, I don't think this will make a difference there.

Comment: ,thank you for your answer. I'll vote up after getting 15 or more reputation. If you have a little time, could you look through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16567507/how-to-handle-collections-with-the-visitor-pattern)? It's another question about the visitor design pattern.